# Query for Polygon in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, polygon

I am trying to query for records within the following Polygon using #standardSQL:

```
POLYGON(( -139.833984375 16.97274101999902, -138.33984375 15.029685756555674, -67.060546875 48.516604348867475,  -68.37890625 49.89463439573421, -139.833984375  16.97274101999902))
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT *

FROM `ais-data-analysis.adsb.target_updates` a

WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN '2019-09-16 13:00:00' AND '2019-09-16 14:30:59')  AND ST_DWithin( ST_GeogFromText( 'POLYGON(( -139.833984375 16.97274101999902, -138.33984375 15.029685756555674, -67.060546875 48.516604348867475,  -68.37890625 49.89463439573421, -139.833984375  16.97274101999902))'),
      ST_GeogPoint(-139.833984375 ,
        16.97274101999902),
      10)
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

My Query runs but the data returned doesn't account for the polygon parameters and instead returns all records from the given time above. I myself am also unsure as to how to approach polygons in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below expression is always true that is why!

```
ST_DWithin(
  ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON(( -139.833984375 16.97274101999902, -138.33984375 15.029685756555674, -67.060546875 48.516604348867475,  -68.37890625 49.89463439573421, -139.833984375  16.97274101999902))'), 
  ST_GeogPoint(-139.833984375, 16.97274101999902), 
  10)
```

The reason is that the first vertex in involved poligon is the same as the point you use

You can also see this from visualization below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the help Mikhail, and thanks more for the visual steps.

Comment: yes, just realized I didn't accept your answer as helped best, just did now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test again a variable, not a constant:

```
SELECT ST_DWithin( 
  ST_GeogFromText( 
    'POLYGON(( -139.833984375 16.97274101999902, -138.33984375 15.029685756555674, -67.060546875 48.516604348867475,  -68.37890625 49.89463439573421, -139.833984375  16.97274101999902))')
  , ST_GeogPoint(-139.833984375 , 16.97274101999902)
  , 10)
```

The value of that statement is `true` - so everything will be returned.

Instead have `ST_GeogPoint(-139.833984375 , 16.97274101999902)` be a column from the queried table.